# Fixtures in unit testing for a standalone bundle

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, symfony, fixtures

i wrote a standalone bundle for symfony and doctrine, and i want to unit test it with phpunit
i need a database, entities and fixtures to test my bundle.
I followed this nice gist to create an App included into my bundle :
https://gist.github.com/K-Phoen/4494091

Everything is going nice, except for the doctrine mapping. I got a "No Metadata Classes to process." message each time i try to update the database.
Here is my doctrine config :

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        mappings:
            C2is\DoctrineCacheInvalidationBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity:    
                type:                 annotation
                dir:                  "%kernel.root_dir%/../Entity"
                is_bundle:            false
                prefix:               DoctrineCacheInvalidationBundle\Entity
                alias:                DoctrineCacheInvalidationBundle
```

And inside the directory Entity i have an extremely simple Test.php entity, which is in namespace C2is\DoctrineCacheInvalidationBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity;

i can't figure any way to make doctrine understand the metadatas.

thanks for helping.